# iOS app rejected, trying to symbolicate crash log

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-dumps

I have read the other posts that pertain to this but the suggestions there do not seem to have worked for me.

I submitted my first iOS app to the App Store and got rejected because it crashed.  (It runs fine on all the Xcode simulators as well as my iPad Mini.)  They sent me two crash logs, which I am now trying to symbolicate using Xcode, as described in Apple documentation:

1. Connect an iOS device to your Mac
2. Choose "Devices" from the "Window" menu
3. Under the "DEVICES" section in the left column, choose a device
4. Click the "View Device Logs" button under the "Device Information" section on the right hand panel
5. Drag your crash report onto the left column of the presented panel.
   Xcode will automatically symbolicate the crash report and display the results

After following those instructions, I am seeing the crash log linked to below in Xcode. (Had to link to this, since including it put me over the 30K limit for questions.)

Maybe I need a dSym file?  If so, do I request this from the reviewers, or is there a way for me to generate my own now?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

[greendept.com/choirherence/crash/](http://greendept.com/choirherence/crash/)

Here's a screenshot of what I'm doing in Xcode:

[image: Xcode displaying crash log]

Tried setting Debug to `Yes` under Validate Built Project (it was already `Yes` for Release) and the Debug `Optimization Level` to `Fast [-O]` (matching the Release `Optimization Level`) based on comments from sbarow. After an "unknown error" and a reboot the app now compiles and runs fine on my iPad with those new settings.

http://greendept.com/choirherence/crash/build_settings1.jpg

[image: unknown error after optimization level setting]

Comment: That is not a symbolicated crash log. That's the raw crash log.

Comment: Right, but according to the instructions I quoted, shouldn't XCode have automatically symbolicated it?

Comment: What I would suggest doing is in Build Settings, set your Debug optimization level to the same as release and run it on your iPad mini (this slows down your builds, so change it back if you find the cause of the crash).

Comment: @sbarow - Thanks for the suggestion. The app compiles and runs perfectly with Debug to Yes under Validate Built Project (It was already Yes for Release).  Added a screenshot above of the setting I changed.

Comment: Did you change the `optimization level` to the same as release?

Comment: @sbarow  Thank you, missed that!  Set that to `Fast [-O]`, which is what Release was at.  Resulted in an "Unknown Error" when I tried to run.   Screen shot:     http://greendept.com/choirherence/crash/optimization_level_unknown_error.jpg            Not sure what to do with this, though.

Comment: Quit xcode, restart computer :-(